# IE6 Modal Window Issue

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-6, position, modal-dialog

I'm having a weird (and probably obvious) problem with a modal window in IE6, that works with Firefox and Safari etc; The window is set to `position: fixed`, and is meant to be centered, but it actually showing up at the very bottom of the page, over some stuff, pushed off to the left.

My CSS is here:

```
#overlay { 
position: fixed; 
z-index: 550; 
top: 50%; 
left: 50%;
height: 474px;
width: 500px;
padding: 20px;
margin: -247px 0 0 -270px;
background: #fff;
border: 1px solid #CCC; }
```

The jQuery function that adds this div is as follows:

```
var style = '<div id="overlay"><div id="youtube-player"><a href="#" class="close-overlay">&nbsp;</a><p id="overlay-preload">Loading</p></div></div><div id="modal-background"></div>';

        $('body').append(style);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated; I'd love to share the URL but the site is for a client and is password protected.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know IE6 doesn't support `position: fixed`.

[Here](http://ryanfait.com/position-fixed-ie6/) is an alternative way to get the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/fixedPosition.html):

> The problem is that the most popular
>   browser - Internet Explorer for
>   Windows - does not understand it, and
>   instead of reverting to position:
>   absolute; which would be better than
>   nothing, it reverts to position:
>   static; as specified by the CSS
>   standard.

Can you use **absolute** positioning instead?

Comment: Note that it only applies to IE6. Later versions are fine.

Comment: @Spudley not so. IE7 and beyond, if on quirks/compatibility mode, it will not have fixed as well. if window.documentMode exists (meaning IE7+) and is =<6 (meaning it's on compatibility mode) you are in for this issue. (not really a problem if you control the whole site. but if you must provide a JS library, that's a concern)

Comment: @gbc: I was referring to standards mode. But anyway, compat mode only goes down to IE7-compat (there is no IE6-compat mode), so it should still be okay (there are other issues with compat mode, but this shouldn't be one of them). Quirks mode is a whole other story; yes, it will break things. That's well documented. But frankly, quirks mode should be irrelevant today; anyone still using it is completely mad. There's absolutely no reason to use quirks mode in 2013. (if you think there is a reason, then you are out of touch with the web dev world, and need to catch up urgently)